# Make ImGui Window undraggable and unresizable

Tags: c++, imgui

How do I make my ImGui Window undraggable and unresizable?

I create the ImGui Window/Widget using

```
ImGui::Text("Hello, world %d", 42);
```

Comment: Read about `ImGui::Begin()` and `ImGui::End()`. The former has parameters to customize the window, including what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! Thanks to @HolyBlackCat's comment

Just add `ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize` Flags to the `ImGui::Begin`

Leaving this here, if anyone wants to do this

```
ImGui::Begin("Window", 0, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize);
```